Rejoinders in future
It is not acceptable, and neither will it be.
It is not acceptable, and neither will it.
It is not acceptable, and neither will be.
I am unable to decide which one is correct. Where can I find this grammar?

That sentence would be better with "now":  It's not acceptable now, and neither will it be later.  Or "in ten years time".   You want a  contrast sharper than what is supplied by the tenses alone.

Indeed, I would suggest deleting the and. And substituting nor for neither. Thus, It is not acceptable now, nor will it be later.

Use neither - nor : Neither is it acceptable now nor in the future.

I suggest you go and study this before asking.

Your first suggestion is the most grammatical one, but there are more "comfortable" ways to express the same sentence.
What are we saying? We want to combine two thoughts: It is not acceptable now, and it will not be acceptable in the future.
Since it's the same idea, just in two places in time, all we really need to do is account for the change in tenses. The verb parts of these phrases are "is not" and "will not be." Your examples use "neither," which takes the place of "not." We still need the "be," though, which is missing from the second example. The third example doesn't repeat the subject, "it." This might be okay in a different sentence ("He talks too much, and will not stop"), but with this one it's awkward and confusing. It's best to repeat the subject here.
So, short answer, "It is not acceptable, and neither will it be" contains everything that's needed. But here are few other versions that might be more "comfortable" in tone:

"It is not, and will not be, acceptable." We don't really need "neither" here. This version does away with it and just uses the two tenses to make the point.
"It's not acceptable now, and it won't be in the future either." This isn't as succinct, but it relaxes the tone a lot, and makes the point very clearly. The word choices here are more everyday and casual. The previous choice used an interrupted syntax that's quite common in this "present vs future" situation; when I changed it to "It's not acceptable and will not be," I had to add a bit more, because it could be mistaken for "will not exist/happen."


I didn't find any matches in Google Books for any of the variations in your answer (which I agree with completely). But I did find a couple of my preferred form "It is not, and never will be, acceptable", where I think never is more in keeping with the implication of "absolute, outright rejection" that would normally be intended.

@FumbleFingers Yes, that's a nice touch. I tried "is not, and will not be" just now, to allow for different subjects and complements of "is," and found a lot of results, including an 1868 one that uses "acceptable" but lacks the second comma

I never thought to remove the arbitrary subject it. But now you've prompted me to think about it, I realise almost all hits for is not and never will and is not and will not will be followed by be, and will match our current context. Plus they're both within the 5-word limit for NGram, so there's the chart. I'm surprised how near-parity they've been for centuries, but it looks like emphatic never is edging ahead now
